# How do you plot a line using scaleOrdinal in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to plot some numbers on the y axis that correspond to strings on the x axis using d3.js version 7. I'm not sure what x scale to use. I'm trying scaleOrdinal but the plot is not correct. I'd like the strings evenly spaced on the x axis with a little padding on the ends.

```
const data = [{str: 'a',   num: 1}, {str: 'b', num: 3}, {str: 'c', num: 2}, {str: 'd', num: 0}];

const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
   .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
   .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
   .append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

const xScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
   .domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
      return d.str;
   }))
   .range([0, width]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
   .domain([0, 5])
   .range([height, 0]);

svg.append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
   .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))
   .style('color', '#80ffffff')
   .style('font-size', 20)
   .selectAll("text")
   .style("text-anchor", "end")
   .attr("dx", "-.8em")
   .attr("dy", ".15em");

svg.append("g")
   .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale))
   .style('color', '#80ffffff');

const valueline = d3.line()
   .x(function (d) {
      return xScale(d.str);
   })
   .y(function (d) {
      return yScale(d.num);
   });

svg.append("path")
   .data([data])
   .attr("class", "line")
   .attr("d", valueline)
   .style("fill", "none")
   .style("stroke", '#ff0000ff')
   .style("stroke-width", 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordinal scale is not the correct one here, mainly because ordinal scales need to have discrete (i.e. qualitative, categorical) domain **and** range.

What you want is a [point scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#scalePoint). Also, pay attention to the fact that `d3.extent` only returns 2 values (in your case `"a"` and `"d"`), so what you want is a regular `Array.prototype.map`. That said, your scale is:

```
const xScale = d3.scalePoint()
    .domain(data.map(function (d) {
        return d.str;
    }))
    .range([0, width])
    .padding(yourPaddingHere)
```